# change datasource from js to mysql

Tags: php, gridview, datasource

please I need to make a grid-view like this one 
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28web%29#demos/jqxgrid/popupediting.htm
but the data source would be MYSQL not JS file

Comment: Hi!
What have you tried so far? Can you come up with some code which allows us to provide suggestions?

KR

Comment: You should select data from db, serialize it to json in view and print to the page - this is your js data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample with the jqxGrid bound to MySQL DB - http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/php/grid.htm?web

Comment: thank you , it works with me